# How do I equalize the length of matplotlib-basemap axis with another subplot axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

Any help with the issue is appreciated. I am having a problem with subplots when using Basemap. Using gridspec, I have created a figure in matplotlib which contains three subplots.  I’d like to draw the latitude and longitude axis lengths of the basemap and the axes of other 2 subplots to be the same. But in my current code while the length of latitude axes of the 2 subplots is the same, longitude axes are in different length. How to equalize the length of longitude axes of basemap and the bottom left quadrant subplots? Is there a way to accomplish this?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
gs = GridSpec(2, 2, width_ratios=[3, 1], height_ratios=[3, 1], hspace=0.1, wspace=0.1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])

map1 = Basemap(projection = 'merc', resolution = 'l',
               lat_0 = 39.65, lon_0 = 27.5, area_thresh = 0.1,
               llcrnrlon = 24.75, llcrnrlat = 35.25, urcrnrlon = 31.0, urcrnrlat = 41.5, ax=ax1)
map1.fillcontinents(color = 'darkgrey', lake_color = 'lightskyblue')
map1.drawmapboundary(fill_color = 'lightskyblue')
map1.drawcoastlines(linewidth = 1.0, color = 'black')
map1.drawcountries(linewidth = 0.5, color = 'black')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])
ax2.set_ylim(35.25, 41.5)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2])
ax3.set_xlim(24.75, 31)

for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
        ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)
        ax.set_xlabel("")
        ax.set_ylabel("")

ax1.set_xlabel("Longitude (°)", labelpad=10)
ax1.set_ylabel("Latitude (°)", labelpad=10)
ax2.set_xlabel("Depth (km)", rotation=180, labelpad=10)
ax2.set_ylabel("Latitude (°)", labelpad=10)
ax3.set_xlabel("Longitude (°)", labelpad=10)
ax3.set_ylabel("Depth (km)", labelpad=10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GridSpec and setting `figsize=(12,12)` causes the subplots to be improperly aligned.

I found using `figsize=(6.3,8.12)` produced a plot with the plots aligned.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (6.3, 8.12))
gs = GridSpec(2, 2, width_ratios=[3, 1], height_ratios=[3, 1], hspace=0.2, wspace=0.2)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])

map1 = Basemap(projection = 'merc', resolution = 'l',
               lat_0 = 39.65, lon_0 = 27.5, area_thresh = 0.1,
               llcrnrlon = 24.75, llcrnrlat = 35.25, urcrnrlon = 31.0, urcrnrlat = 41.5, ax=ax1)
map1.fillcontinents(color = 'darkgrey', lake_color = 'lightskyblue')
map1.drawmapboundary(fill_color = 'lightskyblue')
map1.drawcoastlines(linewidth = 1.0, color = 'black')
map1.drawcountries(linewidth = 0.5, color = 'black')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])
ax2.set_ylim(35.25, 41.5)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2])
ax3.set_xlim(24.75, 31)

for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
        ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)
        ax.set_xlabel("")
        ax.set_ylabel("")

ax1.set_xlabel("Longitude (°)", labelpad=10)
ax1.set_ylabel("Latitude (°)", labelpad=10)
ax2.set_xlabel("Depth (km)", rotation=180, labelpad=10)
ax2.set_ylabel("Latitude (°)", labelpad=10)
ax3.set_xlabel("Longitude (°)", labelpad=10)
ax3.set_ylabel("Depth (km)", labelpad=10)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your rapid answer @dubbbdan. Why should I use such special values for figsize? I think the settings you mentioned related to the pixel dimensions?

Comment: The map is taller than it is wider.  Using a square plot `figsize=(12,12)` left with space on either side.  I came up with those dimensions by resizing the plot in a QT window and used `fig.get_size_inches()` to figure out what the appropriate dimensions for the plot.

Comment: Typically I start a plot without specifying `figsize`.  After I have inspected it and everything looks right, I set `figsize`  to make the plot reproducible.  Especially when you are plotting GIS data, you will never really know the appropriate figure size.  `figsize` is used to specify the width and height of your plot in inches.  It relates to pixel dimensions, but is not exacly the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer, it has been very helpful to me.

Comment: Then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) my answer.